# Start ManualResetEvent from Task.Factory.StartNew freeze my UI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, task-parallel-library, task

Please take a look at this function:

```
private ManualResetEvent _manualResetEvent;

public void DoWork(decimal loops, decimal delay)
{
    _manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = _tokenSource.Token;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(_indexedSource,
                new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = parallelThreads //limit number of parallel threads 
                },
                file =>
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                    //do work...
                });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }

    }, _tokenSource.Token,
    TaskCreationOptions.None,
    TaskScheduler.Default).ContinueWith(
            t =>
            {
                _loopCounter++;
                if (_loopCounter < loops && _shouldContinue) // Here i want to start my timer
                {
                    if (Iteration.LoopsDelay != 0)
                    {                                
                        if (StartTimerLoopDelayEventHandler != null)
                            StartTimerLoopDelayEventHandler();
                        _manualResetEvent.WaitOne((int)Iteration.LoopsDelay * 1000);
                        //do work...
                        DoWork(loops, delay);
                    }
                    else
                        //do work...
                        DoWork(loops, delay);
                }
                else
                {
                    //finish...                        
                    if (OnFinishWorkEventHandler != null)
                        OnFinishWorkEventHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
        );
}
```

This function play my files and after finished check whether there is delay before the next loop or not and in case there is delay fire up event:

```
if (StartTimerLoopDelayEventHandler != null)
    StartTimerLoopDelayEventHandler();
```

This event start my timer from my main form but my problem is that my UI is freezing

Comment: Are you using `_manualResetEvent` here for the only purpose of the delay? Or does it actually get signaled from anywhere else?

Comment: Then indeed use `Task.Delay(DelayTime).ContinueWith`. Or, perhaps you can do `await Task.Delay()`, if you use VS2012+.

Comment: And if i am using .net 4?

Comment: You can target .NET 4.0 and use `async/await` with VS2012+ and [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async).

Answer (score 1):

You're waiting on that manual reset event from the UI thread.  That means that you're going to block until it is set, and not allow the UI to do anything else until it finishes.  This is blocking the UI; you don't want to do that.  You should be handling this asynchronously; instead of an MRE hold onto a `Task` so that you can add a continuation to that `Task`.

Comment: Can i have an example ?

Comment: @user3328870 You can find lots of examples on the use of tasks on their documentation page, and on all sorts of articles about the Task Parallel Library which are quite discoverable through web searches.  You've already shown that you know how to create a task, and how to create a continuation for it; all you need to do is store the task in a variable so that you can add a continuation later.

Comment: Is it better to use Task.Delay(DelayTime).ContinueWith(x => someMethod()); ?